# How can I have my checkbox return a value of True when checked?

Tags: html, reactjs, checkbox

```
        interface SearchProps {
    getGroup: (check?: boolean) => void;
    saveFunc: () => void;
}
    const [state, setState] = useState({ checked: false })
        const handleCheckboxChange = () => {
            setState({ ...state,  checked: !state.checked })        
        }

    const searchGroup = () => {
        props.spinnerOn();
        props.getGroup(state.checked);
    }

        return props.show ? ReactDOM.createPortal((

                        <FormControlLabel
                            control={<Checkbox checked={state.checked} onChange={handleCheckboxChange} name="SG" />}
                            label="SG" labelPlacement="top"
                        />
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state: ApplicationState) => {
        return {
            results: state.results
        }
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
        return {
            getGroup: (check? : boolean) =>
                dispatch(actionTypes.getGroup(check))
        }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchGroup);
```

Currently when I attempt the search, the url returned has checked returning "undefined" instead of true when checked, and false when unchecked

Not sure what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The code that you have copied in is completely incorrect based on the brackets and such, must have just been a copy paste issue, but here is an example of a checkbox that might help you. I just made it for you, let me know if you have any questions.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Checkbox = (props) => {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
    return (
        <input type={"checkbox"} checked={checked} onChange={(event) => setChecked(event.target.checked)} />
    )
}

export default Checkbox;
```